# what purpose is adding then subtracting this number in the function?

Tags: c++, encryption

This is code that I've slightly modified and I would like to understand the purpose that the adding and subtracting of 65 in this block of code that I'm using to Caesar cipher and this is the encryption function (see code block below). Also I've tried to replace the "+" in `65)+key` with "-" to decrypt what I have just encrypted but what I end up getting is just another encryption of what was already encrypted.

```
char caesar( char c )
{
if( isalpha(c) )
{
    c = toupper(c); //use upper to keep from having to use two seperate for A..Z a..z
    c = (((c+65)+key) % 26) - 65;
}
//if c isn't alpha, just send it back.
return c;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. Should be `((c-65+key)%26)+65`. 65 is `A` in ASCII.

Comment: thanks for the answer on the 65 part, any clue on how I could change it to decrypt after I've encrypted it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

65 is the ASCII code for 'A', so if you have a `char` variable with an uppercase letter in it, you can subtract 65 to get a value from 0-25 for the letters 'A'-'Z'.

The code as you have posted has the `+` and `-` round the wrong way and will end up with a negative value in `c`.

The code should look like this:

```
c = (((c-65)+key) % 26) + 65;
```

Which breaks down to these steps

```
(c - 65) // gives you a number between 0 and 25 for the letters 'A` to 'Z'
+ key    // Add in the cipher offset
% 26     // Make sure that the value "wraps" back into 0-25 if key made it too big
+ 65     // Convert the number (0-25) back to an ASCII letter 'A' (65) to 'Z' (80)
```

To reverse the cipher, you still need to do the same thing (convert 'A'-'Z' to 0-25 and back etc), only this time subtract the `key`. The problem then is that you may have a negative number after you subtract the key so adding 26 to the value will bring it back into range.

This gives the deciphering code of

```
c = (((c-65)-key+26) % 26) + 65;
```

Comment: ok so i fixed the bug with the 65 part but then tried changing it to include the adding of 26 to decipher it but that did not decipher it what so ever, i tested it with key=17 and input string "test" with the cipher code and got QBPQ then changed it to decipher and got back FQEF

Comment: With key=17, you should get "KVJK", so something has gone wrong.

Comment: Try running it through a debugger, or maybe post your current code as an addition to your original post.

Comment: some how in the code I had `c = tolower(c);` and not `c = toupper(c);`